# How do I create a financial program where I can continuously input amount and show remaining amount in dollars

Tags: python, loops

Trying to create a financial calculation program.  I know I have to use loop but how do I loop continuously when the user input float value?  I believe I'm wayyyyy off but I am quiet curious how this program can be written for myself so I can utilize this.

I would like something like if I input 10000 then ask for another input for expense...  This would give me remaining till I stop input.  So it would look something like this

10000 #income
3400 # expense
6600 # remaining
600 #transportation
6000 #remaining
100 #utility expense
5900 #remaining

Do I have the concept right?

```
def financial_plan ():
    c = input ("How much income do you have? ")
    income = ()
    y = input ("expense?")
    expense = ()
z = (income - expense)

for income1 in z:
    income1 -= y
print(income1)
```

Comment: How can we answer this? What is a "financial calculation program" in the scope of a single function?

Comment: Not really sure on what you are trying to do, but to answer your question you would need to use a while loop to continuously ask for user input. Break out of the loop when the user inputs something specific like 'exit' or 'next'.

Comment: Do you really have this in your code: `input float("..")`? That's wrong syntax.

Comment: Is the syntax is correct? I doubt that. Please mention the errors you are getting, after giving a try.

Comment: Also, there are some fundamental issues with your python use here. You should be using a tutorial, I'm pretty sure that code won't run

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a homework, but still you are a bit on right track so I am answering it for you. Note that you need to convert the input to float, other way around doesn't works.

Few points to clarify your doubts:

1. If you don't know how many times the loop will run, use `while` loop.
2. Use the `input` function to take input, and apply the `float` on it to get float value of it.
3. Put the code inside the function it is supposed to be in if you want it work.
4. Call the function at the end of the program cause Python is not like C like languages with `main` function which is called by default.

It is a python code.

```
def financial_plan ():
    income = float(input("How much income do you have? "))
    while True:
        expense = float(input("Expense: "))
        if (income >= expense):
            income = income - expense
            print("You have remainder balance: " + str(income))
        else:
            print("Insufficient account balance!!")
            continue
        if (income == 0):
            print("Balance Nil!")
    print("Program Ended!")
financial_plan()
```

Comment: Which will give an error when you try to concat a float to a string. This doesn't address any of the misunderstanding of the OP and creates its own error. How does that help?

Comment: @roganjosh I edited, hope this will help the OP! :)  And you were right and quick to point out concat error... blame javascript for spoiling me! ;)

Comment: Thanks @prime_hit  This is not my hw.  I tried to use what I've learned but I'm trying little ahead since I do not quiet understand when to use While and For loops yet.  I'm just trying out

Comment: @dohtem.yp Oh! I am sorry for being so quick to judge! Anyway, as I mentioned in the points, use `while` when you don't know how many times we need to run the loop, and if you know the number of times you need to loop, simply use `for`. Like in this case, we don't know what the user's expenses are, and hence `while` loop.  Please look into a good basic python book or source, its really easy language and you will catch up in few days at max! :) You can pay a visit to : https://www.learnpython.org and https://www.pythontutor.com.

Comment: @prime_hit Thank you for clarifying that!!!! I appreciate it so much.  Thought I knew little about fundamental but I'm so far off.  Thank you once again!